# How to separate date,time and timezone in php?

Tags: php, regex, date, datetime, timezone

The date value which is coming from API is "2015-12-16T22:14:26-0700" now i need to convert the date into "2015-12-16 22:14:26" without using DateTime object. To do that i am trying to match the timezone -0700 in the end and trying split the date into 
"2015-12-16" , "22:14:26" , "-0700"
the below code is returning an array. please let me know where i did wrong here.

the same i have to do if the date is coming in

"2015-12-17 07:00:00 Etc/GMT" in this format as well.

```
preg_match("/.*?([-+]d+)$/", "2015-12-16T22:14:26-0700", $timeZone);
print_r($timeZone);
```

Comment: @MarcB, the OP has, the 3rd param in `preg_match`: `$timeZone`

Comment: guess I should start RTFScreen properly...

Comment: "without using DateTime object" - why this constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should split your string.

```
preg_match("/(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})T(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(-?\d{4})/", "2015-12-16T22:14:26-0700", $timeZone);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-12-16T22:14:26-0700
    [1] => 2015-12-16
    [2] => 22:14:26
    [3] => -0700
)
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/488702

Regex101 Demo (and explanation): https://regex101.com/r/yJ0lV5/1

Your current regex would only capture the timezone offset; if your meta-character for numbers was corrected to include a backslash, as is `d+` is allowing multiple `d`s. Functional demo of your regex, https://regex101.com/r/yJ0lV5/2.

Comment: it worked perfectly. Thanks for explanation on my regex problem

Answer (score 0):

**Regex patterns:**

Get date:

```
/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}/
```

Get time:

```
/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}-[0-9]*/
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but it gets the date and the time separate